# How to pinpoint the source of angular console errors

Tags: angularjs, console

Note: This question will be changed to eliminate old question with lower rating.

I see AngularJS console errors as follows:

*Lexer Error: Unexpected next character at columns 0-0 [#] in expression [#].*

[image]

The problem now is how to locate the source of this error among thousands of lines of code?

## Old Question:

*NOTE: This is the old question, please ignore.*
I was working with a sample application from ng-flow file upload. I then moved the developed parts to my colleague's environment who is using bootstrap for CSS. I noticed that the look and feel changed on from his environment.

I realized that my colleague is using this css file:

http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

and I am using the css file the came with the download:

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css

and both work fine, but they have clear differences on how the look and feel and how layout is presented.

I included both, and it seems the application is still working fine, and the look and feel is now merged.

I am just wondering if there is documentation that explains the differences and how to decide which one to use.

Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they look different is that they're referring to different versions of Bootstrap - version `3.3.7` vs version `2.3.2`. (The other difference is where the files are hosted.) 3.3.7 is more recent than 2.3.2.

Generally, you want to use the most recent version available for whatever libraries you're including, unless you need to stay compatible with an older one. You shouldn't include both, though; that's going to have your users downloading a lot of redundant css.